# ProGuard Error: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am using ProGuard from the command line like this:

```
java -jar $PRO_GUARD_HOME/proguard.jar @proguard-rules.pro > usage.log
```

Here is my `proguard-rules.pro` rules file:

```
-injars build/libs/test-main-1.0.jar
-libraryjars /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Classes/classes.jar


-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify
-printusage
-dontnote

-keep public class com.foo.app.Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    static final % *;
    static final java.lang.String *;
}
```

When I run the command above I get the following error:

```
Error: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

**How do resolve this error?**

Answer (score 5):

Don't shrink library files. This worked for me;

```
    # Keep - Library. Keep all public and protected classes, fields, and methods.
-keep public class * {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}
```